# Cómo acceder a una subcarpeta dentro del Proyecto C#, asp.net, WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webapi, io

Tengo una duda aparentemente básica pero no logro a acceder a una carpeta dentro de mi proyecto (en realidad, es un proyecto que es una de las referencias del proyecto principal), que es una carpeta llamada "pdfs" que contiene 1 pdf que quiero convertir a base64.

La carpeta "pdfs" la puse al mismo nivel del fichero desde donde la llamo para ser más fácil, (fichero operationDB.cs, que está en `services/operaciones/operationDB.cs`; la carpeta "pdfs" está en `services/operaciones/pdfs`).
Pero no hay manera de poder materializar la ruta de esta carpeta.

Sin embargo si pongo la ruta "c:\pdfs" (fuera del proyecto) y el fichero allí, lo encuentro y lo puedo convertir perfectamente.

Alguna idea de como acceder a estas carpetas que están dentro de los proyectos, como si fueran assets? Ya puse copiar siempre al destino y tipo de compilación contenido para el pdf, pero continuo sin lograr accederle.

Ya he intentado con:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"pdfs");
```

con:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"services\\operations\\pdfs");
```

con:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.CurrentDirectory), @"services\\operations\\pdfs");
```

Nada funciona.

Gracias!

Comment: Amigo, tienes la opción de editar para poder agregar el código con el formateo que se te pide en el sitio, de lo contrario podría cerrarse tu pregunta, no toma más de un par de minutos pasarte por el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leerlo, seguido de [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para situaciones en las que necesites ayuda en el futuro y [un ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) del código que has estado empleando y donde te arrojó un error.

Comment: Es .Net Core? Por qué no estás utilizando la carpeta [wwwroot para servir archivos estáticos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: Este es el articulo que necesitas. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/urls-in-master-pages-cs Saludos

Comment: Es una aplicación desarrollada en Windows. Todavía no está publicada. Es una ASP.NET WebApi.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me pasó algo similar y lo arreglé así:

```
 var path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +
             "\\wwwroot\\content\\Calendarios\\" + nombrePdf + ".pdf";
```

Entiendo por lo que has escrito que el tuyo sería:

```
 var path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +
             "\\services\\operations\\pdfs\\" + nombrePdf + ".pdf";
```

Pero de todas maneras pon un punto de interrupción después para asegurarte que la var path está cogiendo una Url con sentido.

¡Espero haberte podido ayudar!

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta,
Sin embargo lo he intentado y el System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() me devuelve
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express
no sé como acceder a mi ruta relativa a partir de la ubicación del IIS Express en donde corre la aplicación de VS.
Así como está escrita la ruta no encuentra la carpeta de pdfs..
gracias

Answer (score 1):

**Si los archivos son fijos, podrías agregarlos a un archivo de recursos en tu proyecto.**

1. Crea un archivo de recursos dentro de tu proyecto:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Abre el archivo de recursos y en la sección superior izquierda selecciona archivos y trata de subir el recurso, en este caso el archivo pdf:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Para acceder al archivo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("pdf", typeof(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application).Assembly);
var str = rm.GetStream("pdf");
```